# Receiving message, "make: Nothing to be done for 'all.'"

Tags: makefile

Here is my snippet of code that's giving me this error, it is in Fortran.  If you want more code I can amend this one if it helps.

```
    [cba78749@bridges2-login012 ~]$ cd FFB0D
    [cba78749@bridges2-login012 FFB0D]$ ls
    BGKVDCF0D_commvar.f90        BGKVDCF0D_spat_oper_mod.o      DGV_commvar.f90            DGV_miscsetup.o      Makefile_debug           bgkvdcf0d_spat_oper_mod.mod    dgv_readwrite.mod  gaussquad.mod       nrroutines_mod.o
    BGKVDCF0D_commvar.o          BGKVDCF0D_time_integr_mod.f90  DGV_commvar.o              DGV_mpiroutines.f90  Makefile_production      bgkvdcf0d_time_integr_mod.mod  dgv_sf02.mod       gaussquad.o         nrtype.f90
    BGKVDCF0D_miscset.f90        BGKVDCF0D_time_integr_mod.o    DGV_dgvtools_mod.f90       DGV_readwrite.f90    algama.f                 dgv_collision_mod.mod          ffbM300.a          makemake.perl       nrtype.mod
    BGKVDCF0D_miscset.o          BGKVDCF0Driver.f90             DGV_dgvtools_mod.o         DGV_readwrite.o      algama.o                 dgv_commvar.mod                gaussian_mod.f90   mkl_dft_type.mod    nrtype.o
    BGKVDCF0D_readwrite.f90      BGKVDCF0Driver.o               DGV_distributions_mod.f90  DGV_sf02.f90         bgkvdcf0d_commvar.mod    dgv_dgvtools_mod.mod           gaussian_mod.mod   mkl_dfti.mod        nrutil.f90
    BGKVDCF0D_readwrite.o        DGV_collision_mod.f90          DGV_distributions_mod.o    DGV_sf02.o           bgkvdcf0d_miscset.mod    dgv_distributions_mod.mod      gaussian_mod.o     nrroutines_mod.f90  nrutil.mod
    BGKVDCF0D_spat_oper_mod.f90  DGV_collision_mod.o            DGV_miscsetup.f90          Makefile             bgkvdcf0d_readwrite.mod  dgv_miscset.mod                gaussquad.f90      nrroutines_mod.mod  nrutil.o
    [cba78749@bridges2-login012 FFB0D]$ make
    make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

I'm very new to PuTTY, and I'm trying to compile the code

Comment: Likely because your question was written in a strange way, with many chatty expressions but without any actual code. And there will be many duplicates for your error message, you should search for it first.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with putty. When you run `make` it looks for the `Makefile` (with exactly this capitalisation) and tries to make the first target it sees, in your Makefile that seems to be the target "all".

If the first target depends on other targets that haven't been met yet, it will also make those.

It is not uncommon to have the `all` target as the first target that simply depends on all the targets in the Makefile, that way running `make` will create all targets.

But if all targets are already made, meaning the files declared as `target` are newer than their own dependencies (sources), nothing needs to be made, and you get the message that you are inquiring about.

I strongly recommend reading up on the `make` command, for example here: https://linuxhint.com/gnu-make-tutorial/

Comment: Actually, `make` will look for either `makefile` or `Makefile`.  And if it's GNU make it will also look for `GNUmakefile`.